# Rust-Cargo: Two packages cannot link the same dependency

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use `cpal` with `macroquad` but can't because 'only one package in the dependency graph may specify the same links value'.

I get the message

```
error: failed to select a version for `quad-alsa-sys`.
    ... required by package `quad-snd v0.2.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `quad-snd = "^0.2"` of package `macroquad v0.3.23`
    ... which satisfies dependency `macroquad = "^0.3.23"` of package `music_visualiser v0.1.0 (C:\...\music_visualiser)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.3.2` are: 0.3.2

the package `quad-alsa-sys` links to the native library `alsa`, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to `alsa` as well:
package `alsa-sys v0.3.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `alsa-sys = "^0.3.1"` of package `alsa v0.6.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `alsa = "^0.6"` of package `cpal v0.14.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `cpal = "^0.14.0"` of package `music_visualiser v0.1.0 (C:\...\music_visualiser)`
Only one package in the dependency graph may specify the same links value. This helps ensure that only one copy of a native library is linked in the final binary. Try to adjust your dependencies so that only one package uses the links ='quad-alsa-sys' value. For more information, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#links.

failed to select a version for `quad-alsa-sys` which could resolve this conflict
```

when updating my crates index.

I think this means that both want to link to `alsa` but cargo only allows one package to do so.

My `Cargo.toml` looks like this:

```ini
[package]
name = "music_visualiser"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
macroquad = "0.3.23"
cpal = "0.14.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macroquad developer(s) created their own fork of `alsa-sys` called `quad-alsa-sys` and thus including both in your dependency tree will attempt to link to the same system library, which is not allowed.

My only real suggestion is to use audio exclusively from one or the other. i.e. use macroquad's audio system and remove cpal, or disable the audio feature of macroquad and only use cpal:

```toml
[dependencies]
macroquad = "0.3.23"

# or

[dependencies]
macroquad = { version = "0.3.23", default_features = false }
cpal = "0.14.0"
```